# GoLang untaint URL variable to fix gosec warning G107

Tags: go, gosec

If I run gosec on the below fragment I get a tainted URL warning: `G107 (CWE-88): Potential HTTP request made with variable url (Confidence: MEDIUM, Severity: MEDIUM)`

I figured I should use the 'url' package but it doesn't seem to offer more than ParseQuery() to detect this, but although it gives an error, gosec still reports as a potential vulnerability.

How to I write remove the warning, ideally using just the standard library?

```
func Run() {
    MakeGetRequest("https://www.google.com/hi?a=7; rm /* -rf")
}

func MakeGetRequest(uri string) {
    res, _ := http.Get(uri)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Comment: https://securego.io/docs/rules/g107.html I don't hink this is about `; rm /* -rf`; it's about a URL being passed in as a string, potentially set from user provided input.  I don't know how `url.Parse` fixes it; valid urls can still be malicious.  CWE-88 is about command injection but G107 seems more about url setting

Comment: to be honest I just attached the rm to show the 'injection', if you ParseQuery it complains, but that doesn't help you re-assemble the URI without the tainted components.

Essentially I want to tidy up our gosec warnings in the CI pipeline and I can't figure out how to make these 'safe' so the checks pass without report. (I work on the philosophy that if you can't solve a warning, or its not deemed important enough to care about, then having it devalues the whole purpose of the report and means people won't check it for more serious issues)

Comment: Have you tried setting the url in a const? i.e. const url = "https://www.google.com/hi?a=7; rm /* -rf" ?

Comment: It needs to work in different environments so can’t be const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using golangci-lint, and want it to simply ignore this warning since you cannot set the url as a constant, you can use `//nolint` directive like this:

```
func Run() {
    MakeGetRequest("https://www.google.com/hi?a=7; rm /* -rf")
}

func MakeGetRequest(uri string) {
    res, _ := http.Get(uri) //nolint
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A way to solve this is by changing the function that executes the request. Instead of using `http.Get(url)` it is possible to encapsulate the request with `http.NewRequest(method, url, body)`, so the request is not performed right away. So your final code could be:

```
func MakeGetRequest(uri string) error{
  req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, uri, nil) 
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req) 
  if err != nil {
   return err
  }
 }
```

With this update, the `http.NewRequest` validates the method and the URL, sets a context for the request and also gives more flexibility for changes if necessary.

Comment: Worth a shot, I’ll have a go at some point and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

As per guidelines mentioned for `G107` you should mentioned the `url` in `const`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

const url = "url"

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
}
```

For better understanding you can refer here : https://securego.io/docs/rules/g107.html

OR

If you want to remove `G107` warning then you should explicitly exclude it.

```
# Run a specific set of rules
$ gosec -include=G101,G203,G401 ./...

# Run everything except for rule G303
$ gosec -exclude=G303 ./...

# folders and files also can be excluded.
```

For more understanding please refer gosec docs : https://github.com/securego/gosec

Comment: We can't make it a const because the urls of our resource servers are different in production to test environments.  I'm wondering if there is a way to run the URL through a 'remove dodgy delimiters' function rather than turning off the check.